# htaccess: redirect all non existing directories to index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all non existing directories to index.php.

This URLs should be redirected (examples):

```
/pages/page1/
/pages/page1
```

URLs not to be redirected because they are existing (examples):

```
/admin/
/admin
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ index.php [L]
```

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is the condition to check if it is not a directory.
- `^[^.]+$` is regex pattern to ensure there is no extension in request URI.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301]
```